# docker-compose.yml services.php must be a mapping

Tags: docker-compose

I've seen this same error in dozens of questions. All say check the indentation.
I can't see any errors with the indentation.
When I try to run I get this error `Services.php must be a mapping` what could cause this error?

```
version: '3'
services:

  php:
    image: may/web-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: $HOST
      DB_USER: $USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $NAME
      DB_DRIVER: $DRIVER
      TEST_PASSWORD: ${TEST_PASSWORD}
      ENVIRONMENT: ${ENVIRONMENT}
    volumes:
      - ../var/www/html:cached

# Persistent data volumes.
volumes:
  database-volume:
```